# is it possible to point a single repo to multiple hosting services like bitbucket, github etc

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

We have a bitbucket repo from the client side and a local git repo. is it possible for us to manage both repo at same time using single local work space?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.  Is it possible to provide a better explanation of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do it. But not directly point a single repo to multiple hosting services. But you can mirror you repo. Here is a [plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.englishtown.stash-hook-mirror/server/overview) for [bitbucket](/questions/tagged/bitbucket) that can mirror your repo to [[image]github](/questions/tagged/github). You can also do it via cli with [the `git` command](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/).

Example:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/repository-to-mirror.git
# Make a bare mirrored clone of the repository

cd repository-to-mirror.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/exampleuser/mirrored
# Set the push location to your mirror
```

You can put this command in a `cron` or execute it by hand to get the mirror updated.

```
git push --mirror
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple remote branches in your Github repository. But in this case you need to push your repository everytime you make an update one by one.